# Should git repository remotes on the local filesystem be prefixed with file://?

Tags: git, git-remote

If I want to define a remote for a git repository that is on the same filesystem, it was suggested to me that it ought to be prefixed with `file://`. That is,

```
git remote add theremote file:///path/to/repo
```

I'd like to know if there are any problems with just using

```
git remote add theremote /path/to/repo
```

I did a quick check and `git remote add`, `git clone`, `git pull`, and `git push` all seem happy with the simpler option.

Are there any cases where the lack of a `file://` prefix will cause an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git handles local paths just fine. There's no need to use `file://`, although there is a subtle difference (quoted from [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)):

> Git operates slightly differently if you explicitly specify `file://` at the beginning of the URL. If you just specify the path, Git tries to use hardlinks or directly copy the files it needs. If you specify `file://`, Git fires up the processes that it normally uses to transfer data over a network, which is generally much less efficient. The main reason to specify the `file://` prefix is if you want a clean copy of the repository with extraneous references or objects left out — generally after an import from another VCS or something similar (see Git Internals for maintenance tasks).